# Non-static methods and Garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a single validation class which has various validate methods. like

```
public class GlobalValidationClass {

public void validatefields(String s) {
//My Work here
}
```

In methods of other classes, I create an instance of the above class and then call the `validatefields` method.

Like

```
public class FirstClass {

public void firstPage() {
    GlobalValidationClass fp = new GlobalValidationClass();
    fp.validatefields("first page");
}

public void secondPage() {
    GlobalValidationClass sp = new GlobalValidationClass();
    sp.validatefields("second page");
}
```

My question is will it increase performance if I make the methods in my validation class static? Or it wont as the java's garbage collector will garbage collect the objects at the end of each method and there wont be any performance impact if I am following the approach of creating instance of classes in every method?

Comment: If the `GlobalValidationClass` has no state, why not just make it a singleton? That way you won't have GC, but it'll be easier to switch validation schemes (you just need to provide an instance of a different class which implements the same interface as your `GlobalValidationClass`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help performance to use `static` methods, because you won't have to create objects or garbage collect them.

When there are only static methods on a class, it is called a [utility class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_class). Typically, you give it a `private` constructor too, to emphasize that you shouldn't create an instance.

There is another option: You could refactor your client class to minimize creation/destruction by reusing the validator:

```
public class FirstClass {
    // Create the validator once per client instance, 
    // instead of once per method call
    private GlobalValidationClass fp = new GlobalValidationClass();

    public void firstPage() {
        fp.validatefields("first page");
    }

    public void secondPage() {
        sp.validatefields("second page");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

It will **increase** performance if you make the methods in my validation `class static` but on the other side there will be **memory hike**(depending upon `static` methods and variables) as static get **memory once** your program starts till the **end** of your program.

and get stats using [jvisualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/), its nice tool, by default its in /jdk/bin/

Comment: The only memory they'd get is the memory the class needs -- that is, their actual code. And that's there whether they're static or instance methods. I don't see where the memory hike would come from.

Comment: @yshavit when their work is over, static wont leave the space

Comment: What do you mean, won't leave the space? What specifically won't leave? The code won't leave permgen either way, and the stack frame definitely will be popped and freed for reuse after the method is done. What else is there?

Comment: _what_ specifically won't be freed? What is the "it"? The only thing "it" is, if "it" is the method, is some code that's loaded into RAM. And that won't leave whether the method is static or instance. If there's something else that you think won't be freed, please be more specific than "it" or "the method."

Comment: @yshavit "it" --> "static method."

Comment: Okay, well, there are two components to a static method: the method's code (bytecode/JIT'd code), and its stack frame. You could maybe also include whatever objects the method instantiated. The code won't be freed at the end of a static method's call, but neither will it be freed at the end of an instance method's call. The stack frame will be freed at the end of the call, regardless of whether it's static or instance. The objects will be GC'd the same either way, too. So I don't think there will be any more of a long-term increase in memory by using a static method.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, have you identified this code as being a performance bottle neck?  Remember, you shouldn't [prematurely optimize](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)!

Realistically, I wouldn't expect you to see much performance gain by making a method static.  But the only way to find out is to measure it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static method if you do not any particular object state. Creating a object every time and then invoking the method which does the same thing is a perfect use-case for replacing it with a static method. Its a more scalable solution.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no state information associated with that validation class (no member variables) and if there is only one validation method then why not make it static (an utility class) Also when you talk about performance you are obviously avoiding the overhead of creating new objects (performace gain may be seen depending on how often these firstpage() secondPage() methods are called) and there is no need to garbage collect them either :)